# Skipping record for expired window for older records and still processes the current records

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Recently I have increased the appid. I didn't set any value for auto.offset.reset config hence it will fallback to "earliest"

The current time is - Thursday, 9 June 2022 20:17:27
While the application is processing the newer messages with timestamps around the current time, I also see few records are skipped with the below error.

Skipping record for expired window. key=[12423495] topic=[app-name-v2-test.groupByRecordId-repartition] partition=[11] offset=[371842] timestamp=[1654541109616] window=[1654541100000,1654541160000) expiration=[1654541460000] streamTime=[1654541475000]

Here the timestamp represents timestamp=[1654541109616] => Monday, 6 June 2022 18:45:09

However these are almost 3 days old messages. Though the consumer has config "auto.offset.reset"="earliest", how is it possible for a same partition, both the 3 day older messages (which are getting skipped by the app at current time) and the newer messages both are attempted to be processed by the app at the same time?

Comment: Hmm... how is the topology calculating the timestamp for the messages that it is processing?

Comment: I think with the default ctx.timestamp() which is equivalent to the timestamp attached to the record at the creation time in kafka broker.

Comment: I doubt if the skipping records are due to the processing of events which are part of windowedAggregateStore. Is it possible to receive the newer records by the topology while the events in windowedAggregateStore are being processed with older timestamps? @GeoJim